# How do I use “if __name__ == '__main__':” in a .bat file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, multiprocessing, program-entry-point

I have a multiprocessing function that runs fine in Spyder like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    global results
    p = Pool(20)
    results = p.map(get_api_item, date_list)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()

result = pd.concat(results)

path = r'<path>'
result.to_csv(os.path.join(path,r'api_item.csv'), index=False)
```

When I run that .py file in a .bat file...

```
@echo off
"E:\Python\Anaconda3\python.exe" "E:\Projects\api.py" %*
pause
```

...I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_ma
in
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_m
ain_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "E:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "<path to api>\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    result = pd.concat(results)
NameError: name 'results' is not defined
```

I think this is because the service (.bat file) is likely not calling it `__main__`. How do I remedy this?

Comment: What happens when you remove that `global`?

Comment: What is there _besides_ the "main" code? Everything that depends on that block should be in the same block.

Comment: @erip same result/error

Comment: You haven't given us the code in the error `result = pd.concat(results)`...

Comment: I think you don't want globals and that `pd.concat` business is relying on it. :-)

Comment: I updated my question to include the rest of the code that depends on that block. Tried putting it all in that block and....everything ran perfectly. Best resource to read to not be so ignorant about why?

Comment: has absolutely nothing to do with the `.BAT` file.  All your batch file is doing is executing python. The error is coming from python, not the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read and understand the warning in the mutiprocessing docs (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) starting at:

> Safe importing of main module
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a
>   starting a new process).

Your module will be imported by other processes, so you cannot have code at the global (outermost) level depending on code in your `__main__` block.